# High CPU with a timestamp column

Tags: sql, mariadb

In a project, this SQL query "saturates" my VPS CPU (it's a small 1-core VPS and 2 GB of RAM).

```
select
    `orders_super_parents`.`id`,
    `orders`.`id` as `order_lastUpdatedAt_id`,
    `orders_dates`.`date_for_stats_filter` as `orderDate__date_for_stats_filter`
from `orders_super_parents`
inner join `orders` 
    on `orders_super_parents`.`order_id_last_updated_at` = `orders`.`id`
inner join `orders_dates` on `orders`.`id` = `orders_dates`.`order_id`
where `orders_super_parents`.`deleted_at` is null
order by `orders_super_parents`.`row_number` desc
limit 15 offset 0
```

Technologies I use: PHP 8.0 / Laravel 8 / MariaDB 10.6.

On the other hand, when I replace the line `orders_dates.date_for_stats_filter as orderDate__date_for_stats_filter` (which is a timestamp type column) by `orders_dates.id as orderDate__date_for_stats_filter` (which is a simple integer id), everything works quickly at nickel (my SQL request seconds is processed in 0.0024 seconds) instead of 0.5950 seconds, I see it when I debug PhpmMyAdmin).

To try to debug, I ran these 2 SQL queries with EXPLAIN (I did screenshots):

With the timestamp `orders_dates.date_for_stats_filter` column (the SQL query which is slow):

http://www.cms-v2-preprod.daw-dev.fr/medias/app/upload/avec-date_for_stats_filter.png

With the integer `orders_dates.id` column:

http://www.cms-v2-preprod.daw-dev.fr/medias/app/upload/avec-id.png

What could cause this, and how can I fix it?

Answer (score 0):

You have a good clue -- about order_date.

First, let me ask you if it is simply a date.  If so, why is it in a separate table?

Given that it needs to be separate, let's delay fetching it.  Currently, you fetch the date for all combinations of the other two table that are not 'deleted'.

```
SELECT  x.id, x.order_lastUpdatedAt_id, od.date_for_stats_filter AS filter_date
    FROM (
        SELECT  `sp`.`id`, `orders`.`id` as `order_lastUpdatedAt_id`
            from  `orders_super_parents` AS sp
            inner join  `orders`  ON `sp`.`order_id_last_updated_at` = `orders`.`id`
            where  `sp`.`deleted_at` is null
            order by  `sp`.`row_number` desc
            limit  15 offset 0 
         ) AS x
    inner join  `orders_dates` AS od  ON x.order_lastUpdatedAt_id = `od`.`order_id`
    order by  x.`row_number` desc    -- yes, this is repeated
```

Some indexes:

```
od:  INDEX(order_id,  date_for_stats_filter)
sp:  INDEX(deleted_at, row_number, order_id_last_updated_at,  id)
```

Comment: Yes it is a simple date (timestamp column). I created a special table, because in it I store several dates according to the actions of the orders.
Doing a subquery in the ROM, solves my problem.
Thanks very much